# LINQ GroupBy Month and Color Count

Tags: linq

I have a database with fields:

```
Month
Color
```

So for example it could be:

```
Month, Color
Jan, Red,
Jan, Blue,
Jan, Red,
Feb, Yellow,
Feb, Red,
Feb, Red
```

I need to get an objected grouped by month and by color count, so:

```
Jan - Red - 2
Jan - Blue - 1
Feb - Yellow - 1
Feb - Red - 2
```

I got as far as:

```
GroupBy(x => new {x.Month, x.Color}, (key, group) => new
        {
            Key1 = key.Month,
            Key2 = key.Color,
        });
```

I can't seem to get an object grouped by month and then color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = l.GroupBy(x => new {x.Month, x.Color})
           .Select( g => new { g.Key.Month, g.Key.Color , Count = g.Count()}).ToList();
```

Comment: I have having issues getting jQuery to recognise the object. Is there a way I can get I to go into an array: ie foreach x => array[x.month][x.color] = x.count? Everything I do just gives me undefined.

Comment: I have done it in a separate for loop but LINQ would be nicer.

Comment: Is is just a case of the wrong case? `x.month` vs `x.Month`?

Comment: Sorry, that was pseudocode - not enough room to paste the real thing. I have done it using a for loop for now, but I was wondering if I would extend the LINQ? I tired ForEach, but my ide says I can only use ForEachAsync which I can't use in that context.